# Front Wheel Squeal When Driving After New Brakes

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor, buick, lacrosse

We have a 2006 Buick Lacrosse. We just installed new front brakes. 2yr rotors and lifetime performance ceramic pads. We have used these pads in the past on the car and never experience this issue.

We first noticed an issue when making left turns. When turning there was a constant squeal that seemed to be coming from the front driver side wheel. Noise faded away when driving straight or turning left.

Noise does not seem to be directly correlated to braking and occurs when no braking is being performed.

After further investigation I noticed something that further confused me. When driving up and down the driveway I noticed that the front driver wheel made the noise when backing up, and the front passenger when driving forward.

I can best describe the noise as something like nails on a chalkboard. A constant high pitched squeal. Perhaps metal on metal.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: This sounds like the "squealer" (brake pad wear indicator) is making contact with the rotor. Are you sure you put the brake pads in correctly? As in, are you sure the pads with the metal squealer tabs were put on where the old ones came off?

Comment: @Paulster2 Yes, nearly 100% sure.  I actually don't believe they will fit in incorrectly in this car, I think the inside and outside pads are different size.  The noise sounds like the squealer, but even if the pads were switched I don't see how the squealer could be making contact with the rotor over the thick new pads.  I'll take a peek today to confirm.

Comment: You can have left and right side brake pads with the squealers meant for the top or bottom of the caliper, if you were considering I was suggesting inside/outside only.

Comment: Did new pads and rotors on my 2002 impala an got the loud squeal when turning right. Pulled it up on ramps, jammed a flathead behind that little tab on the bottom of the driver front rotor, and gave it a couple taps with a hammer. Squeal disappeared immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found what was causing the noise. There is a small metal plate, roughly sized and shaped like a one of those little wooden ice cream spoons that come with a Dixie cup. It is positioned suspending from the bottom of the hub parallel to the back of the rotor. On both sides of the car it was touching the rotor causing the noise.

[image]

On the driver side the front portion was touching, and on the passenger the back, which I suppose explains why it seemed to come from one side when backing up and the other when driving forward.

I have bent this plate back a little and the noise is gone.

So the question is what is this little plate for, and why was it suddenly scraping on both sides?

A picture is attached.

Comment: Answer is not a great place to ask a new question. Better post a new question with the picture. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score -1):

It looks almost like a rotor shield that was partiality form off
Late GM models were known to have them intact a customer of mine had a 2009 Pontiac that had the same thing. We bent it back with a hammer and screw driver. Never heard the noise again